# In Swift, how to change table cell layout when a orientation happens?

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a Table View and I try to change a cell's layout after an orientation happens by changing auto-layout constraints as well as a cell's height.

I update the new constraints in a function, say `setMyConstraints()` inside a cell class. If an orientation happens, I try to call `setMyConstraints()` inside `layoutSubViews()` in a cell.

However, this is not the right place because multiple `layoutSubViews()` are called and some of them are still using the old height until the last one. Here are some logs I trace after an orientation happens:

```
cell layoutSubviews called, frame.height = 69
tableview heightForRowAtIndexPath called, return height = 170
cell layoutSubviews called, frame.height = 69
cell layoutSubviews called, frame.height = 170
```

What makes worse is that if I don't clean up all the constraints before the first `layoutSubViews`, conflict might already happen.

Hence, here is the process needed:

1. The device orientation happens
2. Clean up all the constraints for the views inside the cell
3. The cell view rotates and gets the updated height
4. Add updated constraints for the views inside the cell

I can't find the right place to do (2) and (4). I have tried several ideas but all fail, some are pretty close, but I still can't find the reasonable/perfect place to do so.

In another words, how to change cell layout (including constraint changes and cell height change) when a orientation happens?

Comment: Can you please show your code in the methods you mention — `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, `layoutSubviews`, and `setMyConstraints`? What are the constraints you're changing?

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` has an `updateConstraints()` function that you can override. That's a good place to set the constraint changing code.

That method may get called automatically after the rotation. But if not, you can send the cell a `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` message right after the rotation starts, or after it finishes.

Comment: It's not that simple. I have updated my question. I have tried your idea but I fail. If you do know how to do it, please provide the answer in more details. Thanks.